# Dradis + XSLT: Microsoft XML 2003: Processing

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, ms-office

I would like to create an XML file that can be opened in Word (using Word 2003 XML). I'm trying to embed a single image into the document like this:

![enter image description here][1]

http://shrani.najdi.si/?3J/Sm/2YDPWrKn/win.png

I posted the image on external site, because I wasn't allowed to upload it here.

The problem is that this works if I use something like the following (with corresponding references):

```
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/media/image1.png" pkg:contentType="image/png" pkg:compression="store">
    <pkg:binaryData>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAdoAAAECCAIAAADW64G6AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAPu1JREFUeF7t</pkg:binaryData>
  </pkg:part>
```

But since I'm parsing a data from: Custom Data --> XML --> XSLT --> Word, I don't want to use that approach, because it requires me to change the refernces in various places in the XML document, which can't be done.

I would like to use the following approach, which doesn't work:

```
    <w:p>
    <w:r>
    <w:pict>
    <w:binData w:name="02000001.jpg">iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAdoAAAECCAIAAADW64G6AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAPu1JREFUeF7t</w:binData>
    <v:shape id="_x0000_i1025" style="width:100%;height:auto" type="#_x0000_t75">
      <v:imagedata src="02000001.jpg"></v:imagedata>
    </v:shape>
</w:pict>
    </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

The problematic line here is the "" line, which is causing the confusion. When trying to open that document with Word/Oxygen, I get the following error:

```
There is no schema or DTD associated with the document. You can create an association either with the Associate Schema action or configuring in the Options the Preferences/Document Type Association list, or by creating a Validation Scenario.
```

If I remove that line, the document opens normally, but the picture is not shown. As you can see I'm trying to use the base64 representation of the image in binData.

What I'm actually trying to do is to process the Dradis document, which looks like this:

```
#[Red]#

This is my new vulnerability.

!http://www.google.com/.../test.png!
```

I'm inputing that directly into the Dradis, so the above is actually a clear text representation of the text. I wrote some further code in Dradis that does the following for me (before sending the data to the XSLT transformation):

```
#[Red]#

This is my new vulnerability.

#[Picture]#
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAdoAAAECCAIAAADW64G6AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAPu1JREFUeF7t
```

You can see that the actual picture that was accessible on that link was downloaded and it's base64 representation of the picture was inserted into the clear text instead of the link.

What happens next is that this data is sent to the XSLT that must create the XML document that can be successfully opened with Word. Here I would have to find the #[Picture]# elements, parse them, and insert the XML that I'm trying to make work (the actual problem why I'm posting this message).

So my question is: how can I change the above XML code (the one that doesn't work) into the representation that will open successfully in Word displaying the black image inside?

P.s.: I'm not sure why the schema error, I'm using the following schemas:

```
 <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14" 
        xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
        xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" 
        xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
        xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
        xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
        xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
        xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
        xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
        xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
        xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" 
        xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
        xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"
      >
        <w:body>
```

If you have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: I believe I can help as I have create Word 2003 XML using XSLT often. But first to clarify: why does your first XML example contain Word 2007 XML (pkg:part)? What is the "" line you refer to? I assume the schema error is from Oxygen, not from Word.